# How to mock anonymous broadcast receiver for android unit test - kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, broadcastreceiver, mockk

I have some code that looks like this. I need receiver inside the method so others can use this method to be notified when scan results are received.

```
fun getWifiNetworks(context: Context) : Single<List<ScanResult>> {
    return Single.create<List<ScanResult>> { emitter ->
        val success = getWifiManager()?.startScan()
        if (success == true) {
            val intentFilter = IntentFilter()
            intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)
            val ht = HandlerThread("BackgroundReceiverThread")
            ht.start()
            val looper = ht.looper
            val handler = Handler(looper)
            context.registerReceiver(object : BroadcastReceiver() {
                override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
                    println("REACH HERE") // how do I reach here?
                    val intentSuccess = intent.getBooleanExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_RESULTS_UPDATED, false)
                    if (intentSuccess) {
                        emitter.onSuccess(getWifiManager()?.scanResults ?: emptyList())
                    }
                    context.unregisterReceiver(this)
                }
            }, intentFilter, null, handler)
        } else {
            emitter.onError(Error("StartScan() Failed"))
        }
    }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
}
```

I want to run a test like this

```
@Test
fun `when startScan() succeeds, verify single was completed with no errors`() {
    every { mockWifiManager.startScan(mockContext) } returns true
    every { mockWifiManager.scanResults } returns mockScanResults


    val testObserver = wifiHelper.scanWifiSubscriber().test()
    testObserver.assertNoErrors().assertComplete()
```